# Contour Plots - What is the meaning of the contours?

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, maximum-likelihood

there is probably a very straightforward answer to this question but, after spending some time searching the internet, I haven't been able to find it.

We have been studying contour plots for maximum likelihood estimators, for example the normal distribution with values for the mean in one direction and standard deviation in the other. What I am unsure about is, are the contours spaced at intervals of one standard deviation apart, such that ~68% of the results from a random test would fall within the first contour, ~95% of results fall within the second contour, ~99% fall within the third contour etc etc?

Any help in clearing this up would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: You can't  know  the contour spacing without seeing the picture along with its legend or description, unless the spacing you suggest is essentially standard in the field and so needs no explanation.

Comment: From the questions that show up it seems as though it should be standard - they specify that the contour chart is centred about the maximum likelihood estimator for the parameters, and that each contour is one unit away from this. What I don't understand, however, is what the unit in question is.

Comment: If this is a likelihood plot (perhaps proportional to some density function of seeing the actual results given the plotted parameters) then there will be a scale and some explanation of what a "unit" is.  But in frequentist statistics you cannot read this as the probability of the mean and standard deviation taking particular values: they are not random variables. Instead think of the region within a contour as similar to a confidence interval, with the degree of confidence talking about the method rather than the plot itself.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the contour, irrespective of what you are trying to interpret, is simply a discretization of the "height" (along the z-axis) of whatever 3D shape you are observing. As other commenters note, what that discretization scheme is could vary, and I find it surprising that there would be no legend for what that unit is. Your mention "it seems as though it should be standard" could imply (depending on the phrasing of the original question) that the unit is in fact the standard deviation, in which case I would agree with your original interpretation.